# Constant value of multiplication of lines in circle

Tags: geometry

I have to prove, that for any point $E$ in a circle $k$ with diameter $AB$ and point $C$, the second point where line $BE$ intersects $k$ and the same for $D$, but with $AE$, that the **value of $AE\times AD+BE\times BC$ is constant**.

[image: A geogebra recreation of the problem]

I thought you could use the fact that triangles ACE and BDE are similar (ABE and CDE as well), but I haven‘t really found a way to prove something with that.

Comment: What do you think the approach should be? One way is to place this in a coordinate system and use analytic geometry.

Comment: I think you could use the fact that triangle ACE and BDE are similar (ABE and CDE as well), but I haven‘t really found a way to prove something with that.

Comment: Hint: Drop a perpendicular onto $\overline{AB}$. Then use some right triangle similarity. (You'll need to recognize some unmarked right angles.) ... By the way, you should include your thoughts about the problem in the  question itself. Comments are easily overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give a proof using trigonometry: let $\gamma$ the angle $CBA$, let $\theta$ the angle $DAB$ and let $R$ the lenght of $AB$.

I have: $AD = R \cos(\theta)$ and  $CB=R\cdot \cos(\gamma)$.

With the sine theorem: $AE = \frac{R \sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma+\theta)}$ and $BE=\frac{R \sin(\theta)}{\sin(\gamma+\theta)}$.

The sum is: 
$$
\begin{split}
AE \cdot AD + BE \cdot BC
 &= \frac{R \sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma+\theta)}\cdot R \cos(\theta)
  + \frac{R \sin(\theta)}{\sin(\gamma+\theta)}\cdot R\cos(\gamma) \\
 &= R^2\cdot\frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\gamma)}{ \sin(\theta+\gamma)} \\
 &= R^2\cdot\frac{\sin(\theta+\gamma}{\sin(\theta+\gamma)} \\
 &= R^2
\end{split}
$$
So the sum $AE\cdot AD+BE\cdot BC$ is constant.

Comment: +1, very nie. I took the liberty to edit the LaTeX, using the `split` environment often can make those long formulae easier to read.